# Using a class method in __init__

Tags: python, oop, class

I have  the following class, where I want to use the method `location_change` within `__init__`for that class. Is there a way to do this? The example I use below is a simplification but what I need to do is use a class method to transform some constructor data. Can this be done in python?

```
class dummy:

    def __init__(self):

        self.location = 'USA'
        print(self.location)

        location_change()
        print(self.location)

    def location_change():

        self.location = 'UK'


first_dummy = dummy()
```

Comment: It's better to name classes in CamelCase.

Comment: There seems to be some confusion between _classmethods_ and _methods on classes_; sadly, these are different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
class Dummy:

    def __init__(self):

        self.location = 'USA'
        print(self.location)

        self.location_change()
        print(self.location)

    def location_change(self):

        self.location = 'UK'


first_dummy = Dummy()
```

Answer (score 5):

Sure it can!

```
self.location_change()
```

each method in a class should take at least one argument and that is conventionally called self.

```
def location_change(self):
```

an introductory tutorial on oop in python 
http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/OOP.shtml

the documentation
http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html

Answer (score 1):

```
class Dummy:

    def __init__(self):

        self.location = 'USA'
        print(self.location)
        Dummy.location_change(self)
        print(self.location)

    def location_change(self):

        self.location = 'UK'


first_dummy = Dummy()
print(first_dummy)
```

What you needed to do was tell "location_change" that it was working with argument, self. Otherwise it's an undefined variable. You also needed to use the class name when calling it.
This should give you:

```
USA
UK
<__main__.Dummy object at 0x1005ae1d0>
```

Comment: Why would you call `dummy.location_change(self)` instead of `self.location_change()`? This way if a sub-class implement `location_change` that implementation will not be used!